# Flutter easily composite / overlay PNG images from the assets directory

Tags: image, flutter

Looking for a simple and fast example / tutorial to **composite / overlay several images in Flutter**, using (PNG) images from the assets directory:

[image]

Few options I've examined:

1. Manipulate Uint8List and use it in [image.Memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html)
2. Use [canvas.drawAtlas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawRawAtlas.html) in my own Painter
3. use the [image library](https://pub.dev/packages/image) (which seems a bit overkill in this case

Couldn't find any working example that suits my needs...
I'd appreciate any working example / tutorial that will help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

4.Use combination of Stack and RepaintBoundary to generate new image:

```
Future<Uint8List> _takeScreenShot(context) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _repaintKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    return pngBytes;
}

Stack(
  key: _repaintKey,
  children: [
    //your background image,
    //your png image,
  ],
)
```